# Transforming string values in python

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, split

I am working on a dataset which has column that looks like this A ='A123B4567C9876D145789'  What i am looking for is to transform the values where the new column looks like this.

A =  A123

```
 B4567

 C9876
```

so instead of values horizontally make them vertical and also on a new row.

I have tried pd.transpose(). Also tried pd.str.split() to split in into many columns but wasn't successful. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The format of the input is uncleat, `A ='A123B4567C9876D145789' ` is not a Series/DataFrame. Please provide a reproducible pandas object

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear that one of the values in the column

Comment: Please be explicit [edit] the question to provide a constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
df['Column1'] = df['Column1'].str.findall(r'[A-Z]\d+')
df = df.explode('Column1')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Column1
0     A123
0    B4567
0    C9876
0  D145789
```

---

Initial dataframe:

```
                 Column1
0  A123B4567C9876D145789
```

Comment: `expand=True` and `stack` might be more efficient ;)